# Problem using a FindAll enclosure with a groovy collect call

Tags: java, groovy

Groovy Question. I have the following test example. I need to search a collection and collect all events on the same day as date1. I added a findAll enclosure to the end of the collect call since I can't check the same day within the collection. I'm seeing the error "Cannot access last() element from an empty List" checking the .last() method if the List is empty even w/ the ?.last() used in the condition check. If I remove the findAll from the collect call it works as normal and I don't understand why. I always do this condition check w/ the collect call to create a new instance if not in the list, but not w/ the findAll enclosure on the end. Why would this make a difference?

```
Date date1 = new Date();
List<Event> lEvents = test.collect("events").findAll{ d ->
                         DateUtils.isSameDay(d.testdate, d1);
                      }

Event newEvent = lEvents?.last() ?: new Event();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is saying that the list is empty, not that it's null, so the `?` in `?.last()` doesn't make any difference. That 'empty list' exception is always thrown when trying to retrieve the last element of an empty list, for obvious reasons. Your `findAll` is filtering out everything and returning an empty list, which triggers the error.

You say that you always test for an empty list in this way, so it's not clear how your other code is able to call `last()` on an empty list without throwing. Do you definitely have cases where the `collect()` returns an empty list?

To fix this specific case, you could do:

```
Event newEvent = (lEvents.size() > 0) ? lEvents.last() : new Event()
```

Comment: I use the collect method all the time this way and for some reason it doesn't throw the empty list error when using it like this Event nEvent= lEvents.last() ?: new Event(), but w/ the FindAll enclosure on the end of the collect method it does. You can even do a collect().last() call and if the there is an empty list it doesn't throw the empty list error if the collect fails, it just returns null. The findAll must handle the empty list reporting differently than the collect() method me thinks. Thanks for looking into it.